# CSS in _Layout of ASP.NET Not Loading Until Refresh

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project that's configured in IIS to show a "default.htm" page at startup.  The default page has some CSS embedded in it to apply to all pages (along with some HTML and javascript).  The project's _Layout page has some additional CSS in it that should only apply to the project from the first page in the project forward.  I have read many articles regarding loading external CSS files, but I can't find out why the embedded CSS in _Layout doesn't override the styles found in the default page.  Refreshing the page (F5) seems to reload the first page of the project and apply the CSS found therein.  I am new to web programming (html, css, etc.) and don't understand why the CSS doesn't "cascade" as it's supposed to.  It seems to work fine in Visual Studio debug mode where the default page is not present.

Code from default page....

```
<style type="text/css">       
    .checkboxes label
    {              
        font-weight: bold;
        color: Yellow;
    } 

    div.dw
    {           
        min-width: 0px;
    }           

    input.i-txt  
    {
                display:none;
                }
    #directors_dummy
    {
        display: none;
        color: Yellow;
    }
</style>
```

CSS that I want to apply to the first page of project forward (in addition to the default CSS)...

```
<style type="text/css">       
    #blueBorder
    {
        border: 3px solid blue;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? I know what you're asking, but it will be easier to assist if I can see how you have it set up.

Comment: Anything (css or html) in `default.html` will not show up in any of your web forms.

Comment: The CSS and html works in default.html.  The "blueBorder" CSS in the _Layout does not work (when running in IIS).  It DOES work when in DEBUG mode in VS.